# JodaTime IllegalArgumentException Invalid format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

Tags: java, datetime, format, jodatime

Before to post, i search this format in previous questions but i dont found it

Here is the simple code that i want to try :

```
String YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
DateTimeFormatter yyyyMMddHHmmssFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS); 
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.parse("2019-01-17 11:01:15", yyyyMMddHHmmssFormatter);
```

I got this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2019-01-17 11:01:15" is malformed at "-01-17 11:01:15"
```

I think, i must change something in the string format ?

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud use format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` for input `2019-01-17 11:01:15`, `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` works when the input like `2019/01/17 11:01:15`.

### Update

You need two format to convet:

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"); 
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.parse("2019-01-17 11:01:15", inputFormat);
System.out.println(outputFormat.print(fromDate));
```

Comment: You mean this YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS must be in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ?

Comment: Thank's, that's what i've added : 

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
try {
Date dDate = df.parse(getEndDate());
fromDate = DateTime.parse(df1.format(dDate), yyyyMMddHHmmssFormatter);

And it works

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
String YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
```

to

```
String YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: How to make the result in format yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ?

Comment: To make result with slashes use a second formatter for formatting back into a string.